# Reporting Interval Between Two Dates Within Same Column

Tags: formula, reporting, formula-field, custom-field, custom-reports

Thanks for any and all help!

This is pretty straight forward but I am failing to execute. It is simple to calculate the difference between two dates if they exist in two columns, however, in this scenario they live within the same column.

Has anyone else had this use case?

My goal is to get the average time it took from Task A->B and B->C ultimately, but I can do that once I figure out how to calculate the delta.

[image]

Comment: are these dates stored on a custom object field in salesforce?

Comment: Given that this is for a report, the only way I could see a static calculation working out the delta for a sibling, earlier record would be to have a lookup to the previous record on each record. Then you'd be able to define a calculation to determine the difference.

Comment: @coderdecoder That is 100% correct, yes.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Oh that is an interesting idea, I don't know if I quite have the solution at the tips of my fingertips but that gives me a thread to pull! Thank you.